# Is there a way to change/customize images on AddThis script/widget?

Tags: javascript, facebook, widget, addthis

So we're using the script from [this site](http://www.addthis.com/web-button?where=website&type=bm&clickbacks=1&frm=home&bm=tb11&analytics=0) to share stuff on our site.

However, we like to change the icons/buttons that it uses as a default. Is there a way to change them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can change your toolbox and use the icons you want.

Check the "Custom Images" section of [this page](http://www.addthis.com/help/toolbox).

Answer (score 2):

See:
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/questions/1521845-why-do-my-icons-change-randomly-

> These are different for each individual based on their past sharing history and what services are most popular in our service...

Instead of using `addthis_button_preferred_1`, `addthis_button_preferred_2`, ... its better to use the following which clearly states what service each image maps to:

```html
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style">
  <a class="addthis_button_email">
      <img src="<URL>/email-share.png" width="80" border="0" alt="Share" />
    </a>
  <a class="addthis_button_facebook">
      <img src="<URL>/fb-share.png" width="80" border="0" alt="Share" />
    </a>
  <a class="addthis_button_google_plusone_share">
      <img src="<URL>/googleplus-share.png" width="80" border="0" alt="Share" />
    </a>
  <a class="addthis_button_linkedin">
      <img src="<URL>/linkedin-share.png" width="80" border="0" alt="Share" />
    </a>
  <a class="addthis_button_twitter">
      <img src="<URL>/twitter-share.png" width="80" border="0" alt="Share" />
    </a>
  <a class="addthis_button_compact">
      <img src="<URL>/addthis-share.png" width="80" border="0" alt="Share" />
    </a>
</div>
```

Replace the URL part according to your needs.